# Changing HTML id via JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hava a script that consist of "hello world" and the "hello" and "world" are in two different CSS styles.

I would like to click onto either of them and they would swap their styles. Example is I click on "hello" and it would swap style with "world". Below is my codes.

I couldn't get it to swap. How should I correct it ?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#today{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}

#normal{
    font-weight: normal;
    color: green;
}
</style>
<script>
    old="old";

        function set(in){
            var e = document.getElementsByName(old);
            for(ii=0;ii<e.length; ii++)
            {
                var obj = document.getElementsByName(old).item(ii);
                obj.id="normal";
            }
            old=in;
    var e = document.getElementsByName(old);
            for(ii=0;ii<e.length; ii++)
            {
                var obj = document.getElementsByName(old).item(ii);
                obj.id="today";
            }
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="normal" name="new" onclick="set('new')">Hello</td>
        <td id="today" name="old" onclick="set('old')">World</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that "name" is really a valid attribute for `<td>` elements. You can use non-standard attributes and they'll often or even usually work, but it's a little suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems here.  First, in your onclick handler, it has to be "javascript:set" instead of just "set".  Second, you have a parameter named "in" which is a Javascript keyword.  Change all references of it to "inv".  If you do that, your code will sort-of work.  Try it.

Beyond that, I suggest that you work in Firefox, and get the Firebug add-in, so that you can open the console.  It will show you  these kinds of errors.

Comment: However, to do what you're after, you shouldn't swap IDs.  Instead you should work on swapping classes.  IDs should be used to establish a permanent identity for a given DOM element.  Swapping classes is a bit trickier in straight Javascript, but very easy if you use jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

At any time, only one element can be annotated with an ID. Therefore, you should use classes instead of IDs to annotate your elements. Also, make sure to include a doctype.

[**Live demo**](http://phihag.de/2011/so/css-classes.html) of the corrected code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.today{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}

.normal{
    font-weight: normal;
    color: green;
}
</style>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.normal,.today');
  for (var i = 0;i < els.length;i++) {
    els[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
      var els = document.querySelectorAll('.normal,.today');
      for (var i = 0;i < els.length;i++) {
        var currentClass = els[i].getAttribute('class');
        var newClass = currentClass == 'today' ? 'normal' : 'today';
        els[i].setAttribute('class', newClass);
      }
    }, false);
  }
}, false);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="normal">Hello</td>
        <td class="today">World</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, it's way easier to write with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) ([**demo**](http://phihag.de/2011/so/css-classes-jquery.html)):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.normal,.today').click(function() {
    $('.normal,.today').each(function(i, el) {
      var $el = $(el);
      if ($el.hasClass('today')) {
        $el.removeClass('today');
        $el.addClass('normal');
      } else {
        $el.removeClass('normal');
        $el.addClass('today');
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You usually want to put all the JavaScript code inside a immediately invoked function expression: `(function () { /* all code here */ });` to enter a local scope and therefore prevent global namespace pollution...

Comment: @Šime Vidas Already did that in the jQuery version, added that in the regular JavaScript one too.

Comment: Thanks for the advance about using classes. It seems to be a more elegant approach via classes.